# How to increse apache 2 and mysql performance and howmany users can give exam at a time in my server

Tags: mysql, apache, moodle

i am using moodle 3.2 , mysql - 5.5.49 0ubantu0.12.04.1 , Apache 2

And 48 GB RAM , 1 TB HDD, ubutu 14.04 LTS Command based OS ,

i have 500 users but when 200 users give exam at a time then server speed is very slow, server take 2 or more minute to open a question .

Please help me how can i provide a exam for 500 users at a time

**Detail of  mysql and apache2 and php -->
my.cnf  for mysql**

***My.cnf***

```
key_buffer        = 16M
max_allowed_packet    = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8

myisam-recover         = BACKUP
max_connections        = 500
 (#table_cache            = 64
 (#thread_concurrency     = 10

query_cache_limit    = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M


quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet    = 16M



key_buffer        = 16M
```

***apache2.conf for apache2***

```
   StartServers          5
    MinSpareServers       5
    MaxSpareServers      10
    ServerLimit           400      
    MaxClients         350
    MaxRequestsPerChild   5
```

and memory detail is ---: (Command Free)

Memory

```
Total - 49748700

used - 895628

free - 48859072

shared - 0

buffers - 164848

cached - 488188

Buffers/cache

used - 242592

free - 49506108

Swap

total - 134217724

used - 0

free - 134217724
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my best pratice, it will make your moodle much faster:

For apache performance - use NGINX/PHP-fpm instead.... see https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Install_Moodle_On_Ubuntu_with_Nginx/PHP-fpm

For MySQL - use mariaDB10, and use http://mysqlyuner.pl for tuning.

Which caching option do you use ? Memcache ? Redis ?